# Saving Sound Preference Libgdx Android

Tags: java, button, audio, libgdx, preferences

Trying to make an image for sound control. Need to make an image turn music on and off. And save it so that the music doesn't restart every time you go back to the main menu. Trying to use preferences any help would be appreciated.

```
private Preferences prefs;
private boolean spref = true;


prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("Soundpref");
prefs.putBoolean("soundOn", true);
intro = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("Sound/intro.wav"));

  if (prefs.getBoolean("Sound", true))
    {
        intro.play();
    }
```

and this is my image listener

```
   if (menuPanel.spressed && spref == true) {
       intro.stop();
       prefs.flush();
       prefs.putBoolean("Sound", false);
       spref = false;
   }
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: this is not working.. sound doesnt play

Comment: Why do you use different names in prefs? "soundOn" and "Sound" ?

Comment: didnt notice... will try it and post if it worked..

Comment: Wow cant believe i guess the code and it was right the first time... cool!! thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with different names in prefs: `soundOn` and `Sound`.
The same variable should be used.

*Also notice that `prefs.getBoolean("variable", true)` would return true if that variable doesn't exist.*